# Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ . Identify which of the following statements is true:

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $d < \infty$, over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $U$ be a vector subspace of $V$ . Let $S$ be a subset of $V$. Identify which of the following statements is true:
>   (a) If $S$ is a basis of $V$ then $U \cap S$ is a basis of $U$.
>   (b) If $U\cap S$ is a basis of $U$ and $\{s + U \in V/U \mid s \in S\}$ is a basis of $V/U$ then $S$ is a basis of $V$ .
>   (c) If $S$ is a basis of $U$ as well as $V$ then the dimension of $U$ is $d$.

---

Totally stuck on this problem. Can I able to get some help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(a) is False. Consider the following counterexample: $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ (the plane) and let U be the line $y=x$. The standard basis $S=\{< 1,0>,<0,1>\}$ is a basis for V, but then $U\cap S = \emptyset$, which is not a basis for U.

(c) is True. A basis defines the dimension of a vector space, so if some set of vectors is a basis for two different spaces, then the spaces have the same dimension, namely $d$.

Still working on (b)...

Answer (score 0):

(a) It is false. If $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $U=\left \{ \left ( x,y,z \right )\mid x=y,z=0 \right \}$ and $S$ is the standard basis for $V$, then $U\cap S=\phi $ is not a basis for $U$.

Answer (score 0):

a)False
b) Without a doubt, it's TRUE.
If $v \in V$.Because $v+U \in V/U$ and $ S+U $ is a basic of $V/U$, there exists $s_1,..,s_k$ and $u \in U$ such that:
i)$s_i \in S; u \in U$
ii)$v=s_1+s_2+..+s_k +u$
(1)
And on other hand , $S\cap U$ is also a basis of $U $ , therefore $u $ can be presented as a linear combination of $S$.(2)
From (1);(2) we can imply the statement is TRUE
c) True.According to the hypothesis, we have:
$span(S)=U;span(S)=V \Rightarrow dimU=dimV$

Comment: Actually b) can only happen if  $U=0$ and $S$ is a basis of $V$.